# App Store rejected App with Apple Watch Companion App update

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, watchkit, apple-watch

Hello friends I have this issue,

I uploaded the build to iTunesConnect to be reviewed,  but in the review it was rejected because it doesn't seem to have a connection between the Parent App and the Watch App(When you log in on the App, the Watch should be logged in also, but in their tests this wasn't happening), that was strange so i started to run my tests, but in xcode everything was OK, the connection between apps is perfect, there's a missing step before submitting the App that i missed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question needs more information, please provide some implementation details

Comment: Did you try that on actual devices? Because I think thats what they do and maybe the iOS Simulator behaves a little different.

Comment: At this moment is imposible for me to test on an actual Apple Watch, I followed the development guidelines to create and test the Watch App but it was rejected anyway...

Comment: Need more details on your log in process. Can the user log in from the watch or only the phone or both? How do you determine log in state?

Answer (score 0):

First, Run the app on actual devices.

Second, You must provide details in iTunes Connect if your app supports login to a server.

They must accept the app.